# Parsing txt file where each line has a different structure

Tags: c#, streamreader

So, let's say I have a txt file with some unordered data like this :

```
Date Month Year               Position           Workdays
Company                Name Surname Family Name
-------------------------------------------------------------
Days     20                  Holidays             3
Salary  0000.00              Tax                  0000.00
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I parse the data I need (days/holidays numbers, names, etc.), given that each line has a different structure in terms of strings and not every line is important ?

Comment: Is there any consistency to things at all? Like, is this a specific format for every file of the same type?

Comment: Yes, the format is the same for every file.

Comment: Then I would suggest you read the file line-by-line, discard the ones you aren't interested in, and write code to split up / parse the ones you are interested in. It looks to me like each field in the lower section has a fixed width.

Comment: By line-by-line, do you mean without a loop ? Because some of the lines contain different number of strings, so that would mean in the first line I would need let's say the first 3 strings (DD/MM/YYYY), but on line 2 I would need the name (second, third and fourth). I would need a lot of conditions based on the number of the line, given that the example I have given is not the full file.

Comment: Yes, likely without a loop.

Comment: "...on line 2 I would need the name (second, third and fourth).",  No you will need everything after the `Company` name, because a name can consist of more than 3 parts. (and [some](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls095166686/) only have 1 name)

Answer (score 1):

It is okay that lines have different structure, as long as it a "key" and then a "value"

if i want to parse the following:

```
Days     20                  Holidays             3
Salary  0000.00              Tax                  0000.00
-------------------------------------------------------------
Days     50                  Age                  50
BirthDate  10/10/1980        Tax                  6000.00
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

i can use this code to loop for each line and extract the values needed:

```
Dictionary<string, string> results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Dor\Desktop\CloudTutorial\CodeWarsTest\CodeWarsTest\TextFile1.txt"))
        {

            //split to key/value without whitespaces                
            var split = line.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (split.Length <= 1)
            {
                //Print the dictionary we just got
                foreach (var item in results.Keys)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{item} : {results[item]}");
                }
                // new dictionary/class object for each section
                results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------");
                continue;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < split.Length - 1; i += 2)
            {
                results.Add(split[i], split[i + 1]);
            }             
        }
```

The problem is in the first lines in your text input which has no values

```
Date Month Year               Position           Workdays
Company                Name Surname Family Name
```

if we want to handle lines that has no values,
here are two solutions:

1- we check that the value, is not a key.
i added a method called `IsValueValid`

```
  Dictionary<string, string> results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Dor\Desktop\CloudTutorial\CodeWarsTest\CodeWarsTest\TextFile1.txt"))
        {

            //split to key/value without whitespaces                
            var split = line.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (split.Length <= 1)
            {
                //Print the dictionary we just got
                foreach (var item in results.Keys)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{item} : {results[item]}");
                }
                // new dictionary/class object for each section
                results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------");
                continue;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < split.Length - 1; i += 2)
            {
                if (IsValueValid(split[i + 1]))
                    results.Add(split[i], split[i + 1]);
            }
        }


        static bool IsValueValid(string value)
        {
            List<string> allKeys = new List<string>() { "date", "month", "year", "workdays", "position", "company", "name", "surename", "family", "name" };
            if (allKeys.Contains(value.ToLower()))
                return false; //value is a key
            else
                return true; //value is an actual value
        }
```

another option will be to check the dataType for each key - but this will have issues in keys that expect a string, line "position", "company" or "name"